# Transfer Data from one sheet to another based on criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have to compile a risk register for a number of facilities. Ideally each facility would have its own workbook.
I would need to be able to provide a summary in a separate workbook based on certain criteria.

For example, in the basic spreadsheet below I would need the summary to look at the values in column `D` and return all the data from columns `A`, `B`, `C`, & `D` for all entries which had a severity of `1 - High`.
I have looked at the Index/Match formulas but not sure that they will provide the information I need.

Thank you in advance.

Example Spreadsheet:

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?